# Tabular SSAS ImpersonationMode -- Cannot process cube

Tags: ssas, ssms, data-warehouse, impersonation, tabular

I downloaded the tabular SSAS project:*Adventure Works Internet Sales Tabular Sample Solution* and DW:*Adventure Works DW 2014 Full Database Backup.zip* from: https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/125550

I have successfully restored the DW, updated the existing connection, can open the tabular SSAS project in Visual Studio, build but cannot process. The only error that appears is related to ImpersonationMode. When setting the impersonation mode:

[image]

and attempting to process the cube, the error appears:[image]

related questions note to set the mode to default, but as can be seem above, there is no default mode, nor do any of the modes work.

How can this be alleviated?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the credentials on the Analysis Services connection directly within SSMS:

[image: Instead of within visual studio exist]

Instead of within visual studio existing connection which only threw errors:[image]